# Can I upgrade from kali linux 2017.2?

Tags: linux

Currently, I'm running `kali linux 2017.2` 
Is it possible to upgrade `kali linux 2017.2` to `2018.2`?
`apt-get dist-upgrade` doesn't do anything.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The `apt-get dist-upgrade` only makes difference when there's new dependencies that may remove existing packages:

```
dist-upgrade
   dist-upgrade in addition to performing the function of upgrade,
   also intelligently handles changing dependencies with new versions
   of packages; apt-get has a "smart" conflict resolution system, and
   it will attempt to upgrade the most important packages at the
   expense of less important ones if necessary. So, dist-upgrade
   command may remove some packages. The /etc/apt/sources.list file
   contains a list of locations from which to retrieve desired package
   files. See also apt_preferences(5) for a mechanism for overriding
   the general settings for individual packages.
```

This usually happens when you change your `sources.list` or if you are using a reposotory that has moved to a new main version, as e.g. with Debian [`stable`](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianStable) does compared to using `Stretch`.

Official article on [Kali sources.list Repositories](https://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories) has more information for your case.

> The Kali Rolling Repository
>
> kali-rolling is our current active repository since the release of
>   Kali 2016.1. Kali Rolling users are expected to have the following
>   entries in their `sources.list`:
>
> `deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free`

As you are started using Kali 2017.2 and if you do online updates at all, using `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` have already upgraded all the packages as if you were using Kali 2018.2. It's more like a starting point bundling current package versions as an instalation medium.

Comment: Sorry, so can I upgrade to 2018.2 or not? I do have that entry in sources.list

Comment: It's impossible to get what you already have.